# Connect new mysql installation to legacy DBs

Tags: mysql

I created a collection of DBs housed on an external HD using MySQL on a Ubuntu partion (v 18.04).

I ended up needing to reinstall Ubuntu, so lost the original mysql installation; having reinstalled on the new Ubuntu partition (v 22.04), is there a away to access the DBs (eg, `eq`, `fu`, `op` in the below image) I'd previously created (that currently sit on the external HD) or do I need to load from scratch as I'd done originally again.

Many thanks

[image]

Comment: You're rather vague with details; Ubuntu Desktop systems allow re-install without loss of system data, but you don't specify if you're asking about a Ubuntu Desktop, or Ubuntu Server re-install. Personally I find your question unclear (*which doesn't mean others won't understand what you want*) as you *skip specifics* and provide a overview only in vague terms.  The 18.04 & 20.04 usage (release/partition?) is also somewhat unclear; for us to provide useful advice we need to clearly understand your issue.

Comment: If these databases were created and populated using MySQL 5.7.34 or newer *and* the databases do not make use of deprecated data types *and* they're using an InnoDB engine, then it may be possible to pull them into MySQL 8.x and have them upgraded. If any one item is out of alignment, though, MySQL may end up getting stuck with "inconsistency errors". If you have backups to restore from, this would be the fastest way to rebuild. If you do not have backups, then connecting the DBs to a Docker container running 5.7 and exporting for 8.x may make more sense.

Comment: @guiverc, thanks for response.  Which details are unclear?

Comment: @matigo, thank you.  Wasn't able to dump from mysql at that point.  Can you link to source for doing what you describe re Docker?  Not something I'm aware of using Docker for

Comment: You've not given any details as to what Ubuntu product/release you're asking about, you mention two Ubuntu partitions (18.04 & 22.04) but not clearly stated what release you're actually installing (*instead using the version details as if they're partition names*).  As Ubuntu Desktop can be re-installed without loss of data, no data may have been lost but you've not stated what Ubuntu product you're asking about (ie. a Ubuntu Server install, a Ubuntu Desktop install; or even a Ubuntu Core install - as your given release details relate to partition names in your wording), so please clarify.

Comment: @guiverc, the Ubuntu details aren't really central to the question as far as I can tell, but I was originally working on a Ubuntu partition on a dual-boot machine installed from the 18.04 LTS release.  As mentioned, I needed to reinstall over the existing Ubuntu installation and am now running the 22.04 LTS release--in each case the desktop version.